# How to use FQL(Facebook Query Language) with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, facebook-fql

I need to use `FQL` to get user's current Facebook Chat status. Its not supported by `Facebook Graph API`.

"online_presence" parameter returns the user's Facebook Chat status as i studied on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

But i didn't find anything helpful which describe how i can use `FQL` in `asp.net`.

Can anyone show me an example how i can use `FQL`?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this sdk : http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/.
For use fql you need to do :

```
var client = new FacebookClient(THE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
dynamic me = client.Get("fql", new { q = "select online_presence from user where uid=me()"});
```

I let you parse the result and find how get the access token.